# how to Trim xAxis scale in highstock?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using **HighStock.js** to build the graph of a stock ticker, and i need to display 2 days data into a graph , and i don't have data when stock market closes , so i'm getting straight line from **Nov 27 11:20** to **Nov 28 5:19** . I should not get any line when stock closes, **that line should be trimmed along with x-axis**. I'm having prices in the interval of every 20 mins for 2 days. Below is my code,

```
$.each(names, function(i, name) {

  if(i==0)
  {
     seriesOptions[i] = {   
           name: name,

           data:  [<?php  echo join($data0, ',') ?>],
        };

    }
    else if(i==1)
    {

date3:[<?php  echo $date1 ?>];



   seriesOptions[i] = {   
           name: name,
           data:  [<?php  echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
        };
  }
  else if(i==2)
  {
   seriesOptions[i] = {   
           name: name,
           data:  [<?php  echo join($data2, ',') ?>]
        };
  }

        seriesCounter++;

        if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
        createChart();
        }

    });



function createChart() {

    var date_new1 ;

    var date_new2 ;

    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
        },

    dataLabels: {
           enabled: true
        },


    yAxis: {
        title: {
        text: 'PRICE',
        },

    },

        xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'PERIOD',
         },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        second: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
        hour: '%Y-%m-%d<br/>%H:%M',
        day: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
        week: '%Y<br/>%m-%d',
        month: '%Y-%m',
        year: '%Y'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
         }]
    },

        navigator: {
        enabled: false,
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2,
        layout: 'vertical',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        shadow: true
    },

    series: seriesOptions



    });
    }

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The feature to automatically collapse weekends is not completely implemented yet. It is scheduled for the next release of highstock (the one after 1.0.2). Here is the corresponding feature request: [on uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1089981-allow-irregular-datetime-xaxis-note-irregular-po)